# Does PyInstaller Compile Python File Safely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Does pyinstaller compiles python file safely and undecompilable like Cython does and not like py2exe where they only save the plain code and run automatically in the interpreter?

Comment: No, it is not. There are some tools to reverse it like [this](http://evolvedmicrobe.com/blogs/?p=429).

Comment: @M.R. How about, is PYD file decompilable and reveals the code?

Comment: PYDis like DLL files so it **cannot** be decompiled easily.